# What is the meaning of the "xmbean-dd" attribute in an mbean in jboss-service.xml?

Tags: jboss, jmx

For example,

```
   <mbean code="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl" 
          name="jboss:service=NamingBeanImpl" 
          xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingBean-xmbean.xml">
   </mbean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The optional xmbean-dd attribute specifies the path to the XMBean resource if this MBean service uses the JBoss XMBean descriptor to define a Model MBean management interface

according to section [3.4.2.1 The SARDeployer MBean](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JBoss_MBean_Services-The_SARDeployer_MBean.html#The_SARDeployer_MBean-The_DTD_for_the_MBean_service_descriptor_parsed_by_the_SARDeployer) in the documentation.

Basically this means that for StandardMBeans that usually have no description of arguments or operations, you can supply those in an XML file.  The `resource:` prefix points to the `$SERVER/conf` directory. Have a look at `resource:xmdesc/` for examples of descriptors for MBeans in `resource:jboss-service.xml`.